# Using a pointer to a function as a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

(C++) I've got a number of Entry classes, and got BaseProcessor interface which incapsulates Entry processing logic. (see code below)

The Entry doesn't provide operator<(). The BaseProcessor provides a pointer to less(Entry, Entry) function which is specific for particular BaseProcessor implementation.

I can use the function pointer to compare Entry instances in my program. However I need to create std::set (or std::map, or something else that uses less() ) for Entry class. I've tried to use std::binary_function derived class to pass it to std::set, but it looks like I can't pass a function pointer value to a template.

How can I do this? Is it possible with C++03?

Thanks.

```
struct Entry
{
  // ...
private: 
  bool operator< (const Entry &) const; // Should be defined by BaseProcessor.
};

typedef bool (*LessFunc)(const Entry &, const Entry &);

class BaseProcessor
{
public:
  // ...
  virtual LessFunc getLessFunc () const = 0;
};

// ...

BaseProcessor *processor = getProcessor();
LessFunc lessfunc = processor->getLessFunc();

Entry e1;
Entry e2;
bool isLess = lessfunc(e1, e2);  // OK

typedef std::set<Entry, ???> EntrySetImpl; // how to use lessfunc here?
EntrySetImpl entries;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
typedef std::set<Entry, LessFunc> EntrySetImpl;
EntrySetImpl entries(lessfunc);
```

Note that you need to specify the *type* of your comparison function or object as a template parameter to `set`, and then give it an *instance* of the comparison function or object when you actually create a set.

---

I'll edit my answer to address your follow-up question, because it's a bit easier.

You can define a template like this:

```
template <LessFunc func> class MyContainer { /*code*/ };
```

However, the catch is, you must specify a *specific* function, not a function pointer variable, as the template argument. So, for example, this is OK:

```
bool CompareEntries1(const Entry &, const Entry &);
MyContainer<CompareEntries1> container;
```

...but this isn't OK:

```
bool CompareEntries1(const Entry &, const Entry &);
LessFunc lessfunc = &CompareEntries1; //or any other way of getting a LessFunc
MyContainer<lessfunc> container;
```

If you have used array template classes, like `boost::array`, you might have seen something like this before. You can write `array<int, 10>` to declare a 10-element array, but you can't write `array<int, abs(x)>`, for example. The size of the array must be something the compiler can be told while it's compiling the program, but before it runs. (There are a very specific set of rules about what's allowed - even if it seems like the compiler should be able to work out what the template argument is, like in the `LessFunc` example above, it still has to follow the specific rules. In the case of function pointer template arguments, the argument must be the name of a function, or `&` followed by the name of a function.)

Comment: However... It looks like there is no way to use a function pointer value as non-type template parameter. Right? Something like "template <LessFunc func> class Comparator {...} "

Comment: @Roman - you're allowed to do that as well, for classes that you write, but `set` doesn't work like that. However, the `LessFunc` you specify as a template argument must be a compile-time constant (it can't be the result of calling a function, for example).

Comment: I've tried to use my Comparator like this: "Comparator<lessfunc> comparator;" and got the error "‘lessfunc’ cannot appear in a constant-expression"...

Comment: OK, looks like I can apply only the first solution in my case. Thank you a lot again for your explanations.